# javascript: Inserting Arrays into object one by one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I need to insert the arrays like locations,commodities into an object which is in this case is refdata. I need to insert the array to object **one by one** ..as i have done in the code below:-

But i am not getting the desired output.Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var refdata = {
    locations: [],
    commodities: []

}

var locations=[
    {
      "symbol": "IND",
      "name": "INDIA"
    }
  ]

 var commodities= [
    {
      "name": "Aluminium",
      "symbol": "AL"
    }
  ]
this.refdata={locations};
this.refdta={commodities};

console.log(this.refdata)
```

Comment: firstly fix the syntax error

Comment: `this.refdata={commodities};` overwrites `this.refdata={locations};`

Comment: you aren't "inserting into arrays" you are assigning a value to `this.refdata` - each assignment overwrites the previous one ... `this.refdata.commodities=commodities;` etc is more what you seem to want

Comment: Yes you are correct @Jaromanda X

Comment: Added an ES6 answer since you tagged your question [tag:ecmascript-6].

Comment: Updated that answer for a **one-by-one** solution using ES6's `Object.assign()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `push` the 0 elements of `refdata` and `locations`

```js
var refdata = {
  locations: [],
  commodities: []

}

var locations = [{
  "symbol": "IND",
  "name": "INDIA"
}]

var commodities = [{
  "name": "Aluminium",
  "symbol": "AL"
}]


refdata.locations.push(locations[0]);
refdata.commodities.push(commodities[0]);

console.log(refdata);
```

---

Or just assign it directly to override the values.

```js
var refdata = {
  locations: [],
  commodities: []

}

var locations = [{
  "symbol": "IND",
  "name": "INDIA"
}]

var commodities = [{
  "name": "Aluminium",
  "symbol": "AL"
}]


refdata.locations = locations;
refdata.commodities = commodities;

console.log(refdata);
```

Comment: Thanks bro.much appreciated !

Comment: @ShivendraGupta Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use a shorthand syntax in this case:

```js
let locations = [{
  "symbol": "IND",
  "name": "INDIA"
}]

let commodities = [{
  "name": "Aluminium",
  "symbol": "AL"
}]

let refdata = { locations, commodities }

console.log(refdata)
```

```
let refdata = { locations, commodities }
```

is short for

```
let refdata = { locations: locations, commodities: commodities }
```

If you need to do it one by one, as described in your question, you can use `Object.assign()`:

```js
let refdata = {}

let locations = [{
  "symbol": "IND",
  "name": "INDIA"
}]

refdata = Object.assign(refdata, { locations })

let commodities = [{
  "name": "Aluminium",
  "symbol": "AL"
}]

refdata = Object.assign(refdata, { commodities })

console.log(refdata)
```

*Hint: I'm adding this answer because you tagged your questions [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).*

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to insert items one by one into refdata location array. I suppose you wanted to do some manipulation on each item. If so the below code will be appropriate.

```js
var refdata = {
    locations: [],
    commodities: []
};

var locations=[
    {
      "symbol": "IND",
      "name": "INDIA"
    }
  ];

 var commodities= [
    {
      "name": "Aluminium",
      "symbol": "AL"
    }
  ];
  
 for (loc of locations) {
    // Do your object manipulation of loc if required
    console.log(loc);
    refdata.locations.push(loc);
 };
 for (commodity of commodities) {
    // Do your object manipulation of commodity if required
    console.log(commodity);
    refdata.commodities.push(commodity);
 };
 
console.log(refdata);
```